# JavaFX - Check if a checkbox is ticked

Tags: checkbox, javafx

I am trying to write some code to determine whether or not my checkbox is ticked, I am aware I can write something like to change its state to checked

```
checkbox.setSelected(true);
```

But I want to write something along the lines of

```
if(checkbox.setSelected(true)){
   write login-username to config file
} else {
   clear the config file
}
```

How would I go about doing this? I've been trauling through Oracle documentation but have yet to find anything useful

thanks.

Comment: What about checkbox.isSelected() ?

Comment: thank-you Uluk, my editor has been playing up recently and isSelected() wasn't on the suggestion dropdown, how annoying!  That definitely replaced my workaround :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried registering a listener to the "selected" property of the checkbox?
It would look something like this:

```
yourCheckbox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(newValue){

                // your checkbox has been ticked. 
                // write login-username to config file

            }else{

                // your checkbox has been unticked. do stuff...
                // clear the config file
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `.isSelected()` to find out if the checkbox is ticked.

```java
if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
   write login-username to config file
} else {
   clear the config file
}
```